# IMAP Folders with MailCore2

Tags: imap, mailcore2

I'm downloading my folders with a `MCOIMAPFetchFoldersOperation` which gives me a nice list of all my folders:

- `INBOX`
- `[Gmail]`
- `[Gmail]/All Mail`
- `[Gmail]/Drafts`
- `[Gmail]/Important`
- `[Gmail]/Sent Mail`
- `[Gmail]/Starred`
- `[Gmail]/Trash`

When I'm fetching the messages for my folders I get a good chunk of duplicates, since the same message can exist in `INBOX`, `[Gmail]/All Mail` and `[Gmail]/Important` et al. at the same time. I check for dupes with the messages UID, but a UID is only unique in a particular folder so that's useless in this case.

What would the most compatible approach be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [Gmail IMAP extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions), you can fetch the `X-GM-MSGID` attribute for a message.  This value is unique across folders.

You could fetch the `X-GM-MSGID` value for all new messages, check which messages you have downloaded already, and download the ones that are missing.

This is what fetching a message id looks like in IMAP; not sure exactly how to do that in Mailcore2.

```
a006 FETCH 1 (X-GM-MSGID)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-MSGID 1278455344230334865)
a006 OK FETCH (Success)
```

---

This is specific to Gmail.  You can check whether the server supports it by looking for `X-GM-EXT-1` in the `CAPABILITY` response.  As far as I know, there is no standard way to do this; the IMAP RFCs don't have the concept of the same message being present in multiple mailboxes.

Comment: Thank you. I meant compatible is in compatible across providers. I could of course use `Message-ID` but there's not really any guarantee that it'll be unique, or even there at all.

Comment: There is no compatibility across providers because this 'duplicate message' thing is unique to gmail.  No other IMAP sever provides multiple views of the same message.  X-GM-MSGID is the only surefire way to disambiguate them.  Note, X-GM-MSGID, not Message-Id:.  They are completely different concepts.

Comment: Thank you Max, I didn't know that. Using `X-GM-MSGID` for GMail and not worry about the other providers seems compatible enough!

Comment: To expand upon this answer and Max's comment, if you include `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindGmailMessageID` when you fetch the messages you can access the value from `X-GM-MSGID` with `-[MCOIMAPMessage gmailMessageID]`.